# Why do the (system), (complied code) and other bracketed objects keeps growing in Chrome memory heap?

Tags: memory-leaks, google-chrome-devtools

I have a visual presentation of a graphical scheme in svg. It consists of a large number of elements(~2000). Each minute I load fresh data(there might be no changes) via background worker, then remove an old svg, all event listeners, and draw a new one. Several hours later the tab's memory usage grows on 200-300Mb. And though the memory heap doesn't grow much, it grows anyway. One thing is confusing, the most of time I see the `(system)`, `(compiled code)`, `(array)` objects growing in size and numbers(even "Object" do not!). But never seen them to be decreased. How should I treat this situation?

[image: screen]
[link to screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7H74o.png)